# How to fill the skillbar again with js

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a skillbar which gets filled upto the given value.I am using the animate-on-scroll javascript library and implemented it on the skillbar.

Now what is happening is that on first scroll, the skillbar shows up and gets filled upto the given value and this doesn't happens on further scroll.I want it such that when I am scrolling, the skillbar should starts filling from 0% upto the value and this should repeat again and again whenever  user scrolls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

my code link :-https://github.com/arunoday153/doubt-for-AOS-animation

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.
Currently I see a large yellow area with skill bars below it. When I scroll down, the skilbars flip around.

Comment: On my github link you will see that on first time scroll down, the skillbars starts filling up.When you scroll up the skillbar hides and again if you scroll down the skillbar will be shown but with filled up skillbar.

Comment: I want it in such a way that when ever you scroll down the skillbar should display and it should always starts filling upto the mark

Comment: I don't see that. Each time I scroll down, the skillbars flip around. You may find this useful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp.

Comment: @braed refresh the page when skillbar is shown on the screen.you will see that the skillbar will starts filling from 0% upto the data percentage value.

Comment: I'm not able to fix it but did make some changes. It seems that `isScrolledIntoView` is always returning `true`. I also removed the jQuery `animate` function and replace it with a css transition. https://www95.zippyshare.com/v/ujS0duEy/file.html